# Setting environment variables via SBT to read at compile time

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros

I have the following configuration to set the env variables in `build.sbt` —

```scala
envVars := Map("LogLevel" -> "INFO")
```

When I try to read this variable `LogLevel` in my macro code, I always get `None`.
This is how I read the env variable

```scala
sys.env.get("LogLevel")
```

Comment: Is this env var read correctly from non-macro code? Can you also provide more context on how you set `envVars` in the build (it matters where exactly you put that line).

Comment: I am setting the env variables in build.sbt.

Comment: Without `fork := true` in sbt shell I get `None` even for non-macro code. So I guess `fork := true` is important. I suspect that `fork := true` doesn't apply when macros run i.e. when main code compiles.